# Virtual Box changing RAM allocation

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have tried to change the amount of RAM allocated to a Windows 10 VM - host is Linux - but this doesn't appear to be reflected in the virtual machine.

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I have tried to change the amount of RAM allocated to a Windows 10 VM but this doesn't appear to be reflected in the virtual machine.

You need to enable `PAE/NX Support` within the settings for the virtual machine.

Comment: I decided to update this answer since it was incorrect, but due to it being accepted, I could not delete it.  Since a **serial downvoter**, thought it would be fun to downvote this answer, I made it into a community wiki.

Answer (score -1):

Contrary to the accepted answer, our questioner simply needs to click over to the "Processor" tab in the machine "System" settings and select the box to enable "PAE/NX Support".

Note that if you do this on a VM with Linux installed on it, you may need to specify to install or boot a PAE enabled kernel.  Check your distributions package manager and repositories.  With Windows it should Just Work.

At that point, the 32bit OS can see a total of more than 4gb RAM.  Any single process though will be limited to the 4gb amount of RAM it can have allocated to it though.

[image: PAE support option]